# In Robot framework, can I access a Browser page that was launched in default browser by the application under test?

Tags: robotframework

I'm using Robot to test a native application. This application now launches an authentication page for a third party integration in the default web browser. Is it possible to control this authentication via robot as well?

Comment: Is this browser opened by robot framework?

Comment: The answer will most likely be "yes". In order to provide you a real answer we'll need to have more information on the secondary page and it's mechanisms. Having a real-world example would be good as well.

Comment: The browser is opened not by robot, but by the application. An example is, you have an app that wants to talk to an API and thus triggers an authentication, like Twitter auth in the webbrowser, and on success the twitter webpage opens a URL like `myapp://success?yourtoken=xxx` which is passed back to the application and the app can make subsequent requests with that token.